# DPDK testpmd fails with "error allocating rte services array" on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, dpdk, huge-pages

When running DPDK's *testpmd* (version 11.19.5) on a CentOS7 distro over WSL2 (kernel 4.19.84-microsoft-standard+, I've compiled the modules manually), I get the following error:

```
EAL: Detected lcore 1 as core 1 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 2 as core 2 on socket 0
EAL: Detected lcore 3 as core 3 on socket 0
EAL: Support maximum 128 logical core(s) by configuration.
EAL: Detected 4 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x5000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100000000 (size = 0x5000)
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: DPAA Bus not present. Skipping.
EAL: Bus pci wants IOVA as 'DC'
EAL: Bus dpaa_bus wants IOVA as 'DC'
EAL: Bus fslmc wants IOVA as 'DC'
EAL: Buses did not request a specific IOVA mode.
EAL: IOMMU is not available, selecting IOVA as PA mode.
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: Module /sys/module/vfio not found! error 2 (No such file or directory)
EAL: VFIO modules not loaded, skipping VFIO support...
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x2e000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100005000 (size = 0x2e000)
EAL: Setting up physically contiguous memory...
EAL: Setting maximum number of open files to 4096
EAL: Detected memory type: socket_id:0 hugepage_sz:2097152
EAL: Creating 4 segment lists: n_segs:8192 socket_id:0 hugepage_sz:2097152
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x61000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100033000 (size = 0x61000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x800kB at socket 0
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x400000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100200000 (size = 0x400000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x61000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x500200000 (size = 0x61000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x800kB at socket 0
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x400000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x500400000 (size = 0x400000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x61000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x900400000 (size = 0x61000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x800kB at socket 0
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x400000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x900600000 (size = 0x400000000)
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x61000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0xd00600000 (size = 0x61000)
EAL: Memseg list allocated: 0x800kB at socket 0
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x400000000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0xd00800000 (size = 0x400000000)
EAL: TSC frequency is ~1990000 KHz
EAL: Master lcore 0 is ready (tid=7fa97ee76c00;cpuset=[0])
EAL: lcore 3 is ready (tid=7fa97bb43700;cpuset=[3])
EAL: lcore 2 is ready (tid=7fa97c344700;cpuset=[2])
EAL: lcore 1 is ready (tid=7fa97cb45700;cpuset=[1])
EAL: NUMA is not supported.
EAL: alloc_seg(): get_mempolicy: Function not implemented
EAL: Ask a virtual area of 0x200000 bytes
EAL: Virtual area found at 0x100200000 (size = 0x200000)
EAL: attempted to allocate 1 segments, but only 0 were allocated
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Cannot init EAL: Exec format error
```

I thought it might be related to hugepages allocation. This is the current hugepages settings:

```
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:    1024
HugePages_Free:     1024
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:         2097152 kB
```

Comment: based based on the log analysis, get_mempolicy fails maybe NUMA library is not installed. Virtual memory area for huge page is created but mapping to physical page is not success. Are you running this in `sudo or with privileged user`? DPDK application requires full privilege as it writes to hugepage and uio

Comment: @VipinVarghese somehow numactl was not installed (only numactl-devel), but same results after installing it.
I'm running with a privileged user.
My guess is that the failed mapping to a physical page relates to WSL2, but not sure. (same actions on a Centos 7 running on VirtualBox worked perfectly)

Comment: can you cross check if this is specific to shared linking? can you check with `example/hellowrold` with build `gcc main.c -g $(pkg-config --static --libs --cflags libdpdk)`